# How to build Django queries to get list of data that satisfy many conditions?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

I am trying to get a list of user_id by executing such sqlite query.

```
SELECT
    u.user_id 
FROM
    users u 
WHERE
    u.role_id IN ( 1, 2 ) 
    AND ( SELECT COUNT( * ) FROM purchases p WHERE p.user_id = u.id ) >= 1 
    AND (
    SELECT
        tagged.tag_id 
    FROM
        tagged
        INNER JOIN ( SELECT polled.answer_id FROM polled WHERE polled.user_id = u.id ) AS a 
    WHERE
    a.answer_id = tagged.answer_id 
    ) IN ( 1,2 )
```

How can run that sql using django orm? It's so hard to understand logic querysets like this...

```
Users.objects.annotate(cnt=Count('purchases')).filter(Exists(Polled.objects.filter(user=OuterRef('pk')))).filter(cnt__gt=1).filter(role__in=[1, 2]).values_list('user_id', flat=True)
```

[ForeignKeys Relations Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SC6m2.png)

Please help to build correct queries to get list of users that satisfy the conditions. Thanks.

Comment: Can you in human language describe what your filter should do? Especially the part where you use a subquery in SQL?

Comment: a list of user_id from the users table with more than one purchase, assigned role_id 1, for example, and there is participation in the poll.
participation in a poll is an entry in the polled table

Comment: I am right now trying to build the data model you describe in a toy project but I have difficulties understanding your data model. You have a model for Poll, Question, Answer and then you even have copies of them. What does this all mean? Can you share your Django models? I have the feelings there is much clarity to gain with a simpler data model.

Comment: Ofcourse Sir... there's models https://dpaste.org/pKOk

Comment: I have tried to work out the data model, but to be honest I can't wrap my head around it. I am willing to help you a bit if you want, but that would require a lot of back and forth, so Stack Overflow is not the place. We can discuss it on Discord: https://discord.gg/tDhWSnzZ

Comment: I'm trying to contact you. Could you give me correct discord?

Comment: Sorry, the link expired. Here is a new one: https://discord.gg/z52awaek

Comment: hi, Your invite has been expired((
By the way that problem solved but i have many new questions and suggestions.

Comment: https://discord.gg/TbEZ3Asy7z
your welcome